# Give access to only one directory that's not user's home

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

In my VPS account, I have a folder `/home/xyz/public_html`.

This belongs to a customer who now wants their in-house developer to look into the code. How do I give SFTP access to only this folder?

I have already tried creating a user and giving access as follows, but when I login through WinSCP and change the directory to `/`, its going to all the root folders.

```
useradd dev1
groupadd dev-xyz    
usermod -a -G dev-xyz dev1
chown -R root /home/xyz/public_html
chgrp -R dev-xyz /home/xyz/public_html
chmod -R 775 /home/xyz/public_html
chmod g+s /home/xyz/public_html
```

**EDIT 1**
This is what I added in sshd_config & then restarted the service, but to no effect in outcome.

```
Match Group dev-xyz
ChrootDirectory /home/xyz/public_html
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: You say `FTP access` but tag sftp and usage of WinSCP - do you really want an FTP solution or an SSH based solution?

Comment: Yes, thats a mistake. Need a SSH based solution. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sshd(8)` and the `ChrootDirectory` directive. It allows to `chroot` an SFTP account.

Comment: In combination with the `Match User` and `ForceCommand` directives you can force the use of SFTP in a way that the user can not login to a shell.